# Help with Wordpress custom url rewriting?

Tags: url-rewriting, custom-content

I have 3 problems.
First,I would like something like this to do :

```
www.example.com/myblog => myblog.example.com
```

myblog is template page.
and then when open one post from that page(post are custom post type) url will look like this `myblog.example.com/my-custom-post-type-post`

Second :

```
www.example.com/mycar => mycar.example.com
```

my car is also template page,and then when open post from that page(posta are also custom post type,but this time post will be in subcategory) url will look something like this

```
mycar.example.com/my-subcategory/my-car-custom-post-type
```

Dont know how to do this in wp.

Third,can someone help me to figure it out why is this not working.
I would like to rewrite this url 
 http://www.example.com/data-page/?data_id=123456789 to http://www.example.com/data-page/data_id/123456789

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');

```
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'data_id';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules['data-page/data_id/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?data_id=$matches[1]';
    $rules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}

function flushRules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('init', 'flushRules');
```

This is the way I send data to another page.

```
<a href="<?= add_query_arg(array('data_id'=>32),get_permalink(get_page_by_path('data-page'))); ?>">Data page test link</a>
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Someone to help,...? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the rewrite rules **does not affect how WordPress writes links** (except for the standard links, to posts, archives, ... and then only in simple cases). **The rewrite rules only cover how incoming URLs are handled, you are responsible for writing the links in the new format.** This is different from frameworks with more advanced routing systems, like Symfony.

This means that you should change the link you write:

```
<a href="<?php echo '/data-page/data_id/' . 32; ?>">Data page test link</a>
```

(Using `get_page_by_path()` and then `get_permalink()` seems redundant to me, since you already know the permalink, no? You can wrap it in `home_url()` to get the full path.)

The rewrite rule should then look like this:

```
$newrules['data-page/data_id/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?data_id=$matches[1]&pagename=data-page';
```

We add the `pagename=data-page` because otherwise WordPress doesn't know what page to show. You currently have a page with the slug `data-page` and a custom template, but there are also other ways to solve this.

Also, you should not flush the rewrite rules on every `init`. Only do this when the rules change. If you write this as a plugin use the activation hook, otherwise just visit the *Permalinks* page to flush them.

The first part of your question is not really clear to me. I once answered [how to let a single post have its own domain name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/how-to-let-a-single-post-have-its-own-domain-name), perhaps that can help you?

Comment: Hi Jan Fabry,tnx for response,still url isn't changed,I update a question with your tip.What can be the problem,I'm testing it on locahost?Could that be the problem ?Didn't have time to read all post from link that you send me.

Comment: @user1147: Maybe this was not clear, but you have to change all the places where you write a link, WordPress does not do this for you. This only changes the formats of URLs it can parse.

Comment: Hi,not sure that understand you,I only that in one place(in header),and functions add_my_var,add_rewrite_rules,flushRules are in the functions.php

Comment: @user1147: Ah, you must change the places where you write the links yourself, WordPress does not do that for you. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user1147: `data-page` is a normal page? In that case, you should edit the rewrite rule so it adds that information: `'index.php?data_id=$matches[1]&pagename=data-page'`

Comment: @Jan Fabry,thank you,I didn't know that,now it sends me to home page,this is the link now <a href="<?= get_home_url() . '/data-page/data_id/32/'; ?>">Data page test link</a> when click on link it should send me to data-page(template page) to display number 32,but it send me to home page and url is good in browser,is it still localhost/testexample/data-page/data_id/32 but it displays home page

Comment: @user1147: Can you [come to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/283/discussing-wpse-9168) to discuss this in detail? The comments are not the best place to do this kind of troubleshooting.

Comment: it is template page,and still send me to homepage,I added code like you suggest

Comment: So fix was to update permalinks when I commented flushRules filter.Tnx Jan Fabry

Comment: @Jan, Where do I add that line?

Comment: @Anand: You use my line instead of `$newrules['data-page/data_id/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?data_id=$matches[1]';` in the original code.